# Azure Data Factory Copy Data pipeline just stuck at In Progress status; but not even loading any data

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database, azure-data-factory

Really confused to what is going on.

**Source:**
 
Azure Table Storage - I have done the "Preview Data" and I can see the data. Added couple of filters in **Query** window as shown in the description.
 
**Target**
 
Azure SQL Server
 
**Mapping**
 
Successful
 
**Pipeline Status**
 
In Progress for last 15 minutes. I don't mind it but it hasn't loaded any data in the SQL destination so far
[image: Image of the Pipeline]
[image]

Comment: Hi Chevy M, If my answer is helpful for you, please accept(mark) it as answer( click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in.). This can be beneficial to other community members. Thank you.

Comment: In my case, this error is out of our control. This is the responsibility of Azure.

Answer (score 0):

If you click on the pipeline name, it will drill down to the activity level monitoring and you can see the details for each activity

[image: Activity level monitoring]

Once you click on the details button, it will show you the copy info

[image: Copy info]

If this didn't help, please provide your pipeline run id and/or activity runid and I'll take a look in our logs.

Thanks,
Paco

Comment: Thanks Paco. I opened the Activity Runs & it appears that ADF is reading the source data., but not inserting any data into the SQL target.

It has read 47k rows but has not inserted any in target.

Comment: Did it ever finish? Can you send me your activity run id?

Answer (score 0):

I think the error is happened in your Source dataset query:

When you first choose the table storage as Source dataset, you can see all the data with `Preview data`, for example:
[image]

But when you add the query filter, the data will changed in `Preview data`:

I added the filter: `PartitionKey eq '1' and RowKey eq '1'`

Click the `Preview data` again to check if the filter works:
[image]

The filtered data is the data which will be transfer to Azure SQL.

As you know, Table storage only support you query with `PartitionKey`, `RowKey` and `Timestamp`, there isn't column like `DSP_Status`.

That means you query `DSP_Status eq '***' and Timestamp ge datatime '2019-05-01'` is wrong, the filter result must be null.

That's why no data is loaded to the SQL destination.

Please see:[Design for querying](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-in/azure/storage/tables/table-storage-design-for-query)

Hope this helps.